# Predicting the output of Python 3.6's `math.floor` for input floats

Tags: python-3.x, floor

In Python3 (I am using 3.6) they [decided to start outputting Integral values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/#changes-to-operations-and-magic-methods).

That created the following problem for me. Suppose that we input a large float

```
math.floor(4.444444444444445e+85)
```

The output in this case is being

```
44444444444444447395279681404626730521364975775215375673863470153230912354225773084672
```

In Python2.7 the output used to be `4.444444444444445e+85`.

**Question 1:** Is the output in 3.6 reproducible? In other words, what is it? Computing several times in different computers gave me the same result. I guess then that it is a value depending only on the input `4.444444444444445e+85`. My guess what it is is that it is the floor of the binary representation of that float. The factorization of the output is

```
2^232 × 3 × 17 × 31 × 131 × 1217 × 1933 × 13217
```

where that factor 2^232 is close to the 10^70 that the scientific notation has, but I am not completely sure.

**Question 2:** I think I know how to take a float `4.444444444444445e+85`, extract its significand and exponent, and produce myself that actual integral value of 4444444444444445*10**70 or the float 4.444444444444445e+85, which in my opinion seems a more honest value of for the floor of `float(4.444444444444445e+85)`. Is there a neat way to recover this (allow me to call it) honest floor?

Ok, I retract about calling 'honest' to the floor of the decimal representation. Since the computer stores the numbers in binary, it is fair calling honest the output computed for the binary representation. This, if my guess for Question 1 is correct.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure here, but that was basically it's `repr` even though it was still technically that number internally. Maybe what you could do is force the display, eg: `format(math.floor(4.444444444444445e+85), '.15e')`? Which I believe should give you back `'4.444444444444445e+85'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the output in hex should be helpful:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(4.444444444444445e+85)
44444444444444447395279681404626730521364975775215375673863470153230912354225773084672
>>> hex(_)
'0x16e0c6d18f4bfb0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Note all the trailing zeroes!  On almost all platforms, Python floats are represented by the hardware with a significand containing 53 bits, and a power-of-2 exponent.  And, indeed,

```
>>> (0x16e0c6d18f4bfb).bit_length() # the non-zero part does have 53 bits
53
>>> 0x16e0c6d18f4bfb * 2**232  # and 232 zero bits follow it
44444444444444447395279681404626730521364975775215375673863470153230912354225773084672
```

So the integer you got back is, mathematically, exactly equal to the float you started with.  Another way to see that:

```
>>> (4.444444444444445e85).hex()
'0x1.6e0c6d18f4bfbp+284'
```

If you want to work with decimal representations instead, see the docs for the `decimal` module.

Edit:  as discussed in comments, *perhaps* what you really want here is simply

```
float(math.floor(x))
```

That will reproduce the same result Python 2 gave for

```
math.floor(x)
```

Comment: I wonder if `format(math.floor(4.444444444444445e+85), f'.{sys.float_info.dig}e'))` is what the OP's trying to achieve here... I was reading the OP as just trying to get the same repr they use to have...

Comment: For any input float `x` with <= 15 significand digits, in Python 3 plain old `str(x)` will deliver the same string, except perhaps with trailing zeroes stripped;. e.g., `str(0.12345) == '0.12345'`.  That's not always possible if there are more than 15 significand digits, because there are more such input strings than there are representable floats in those ranges.

Comment: Yup what I'm saying is I think the OP is purely concerned about 3.6 representing the actual value (it being `44444444444444447395279681404626730521364975775215375673863470153230912354225773084672`) rather than what it use to do and just say it's `4.444444444444445e+85`... purely a `repr` thing. I'm taking this less from a nuances of computers and numbers things and more a maybe the OP just wants to "see it" like it "use to be"... kind of thing. Could well be wrong and the OP hasn't clarified yet... but... I *think* one way is to force the display using the `format(...)` in my above comment?

Comment: I think the OP should clarify what's wanted ;-)  If they want "the old output", that's easy:  `float(math.floor(x))` will reproduce the old output regardless of `x`'s value.

Comment: Ahh... which is a lot simpler than my over the top format then - if I were you - I'd add that to the answer just in case and then we've covered all bases between nuances and just making it print the same thing it use to :)

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I wanted to get back the output from 2.7 and also understand the meaning of the output in 3.6.